# Display at most 3 items, and each item has its own location

Tags: wpf

It's probably a long story, but I really have no idea of solving it.

A company produces 3 categories of products namely food, drink, and other, and under each category there are several products. For example, the food cateogory has products of Chocolate, biscuit; the drink category has products of milk, tea, coke; the other category has products of book, clock, etc.

But **at a certain peroid, the company at most makes 3 kinds of products from distinct categories.** For example, in January the company produced Chocolate, tea, and clock; in February it produced coke and book.

```
class ProductBase
{
    protected ProductBase(string name, double price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }

    public int Type { get; protected set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public double Price { get; private set; }
}

class Food : ProductBase
{
    protected Food(string name, double price)
        : base(name,price)
    { Type = 1; }

    public bool IsFried { get; set; }
}

class Drink : ProductBase
{
    protected Drink(string name, double price)
        : base(name,price)
    { Type = 2; }

    public bool IsLowFat { get; set; }
}

class Other : ProductBase
{
    protected Other(string name, double price)
        : base(name,price)
    { Type = 3; }
}
```

Now I need to display the products. For convenience, food should always be in the first location, drink second, and other third. Plus, **even if there's no food product, its place cannot hold drink or other product.**

Here are all three products. LF indicates Green Tea is LowFat.
[image: 3 products]

If there are only two products, it should present like this.
[image: 2 products]

**Each line should have the same width and height.** IsLowFat/IsFried sits at 1st column, Name at 2nd, Price at 3th. **The width of the second column can change so it fits the available width of the container.**

In the demo above, I use this code, but it is very ugly and **the FontSize cannot glow according to the window size.** I tried ViewBox but I cannot handle it.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="190" Width="402" FontSize="30">
    <UniformGrid Rows="3" >
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Width="50"  Text="" Margin="0,0,5,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text=""/>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Text=""/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Width="50" Text="LF" Margin="0,0,5,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="$2"/>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Text="Green Tea"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock  Width="50" Text="" Margin="0,0,5,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="$7"/>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" Text="Beautiful Clock"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

So what's your suggestion? What's the best way to meet my requirements? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any quantifiable problem? "ugly" in this case seems rather subjective, also how exactly do you want the text to behave?

Comment: @H.B. **The whole line is selectable and has Tooltip**. I prefer to use Binding, ListBox/ItemsControl, but I don't know whether they can handle it.

Comment: I was talking about the font sizing, but that it should be selectable means you should use a `ListBox` or derivative. Also i see no reason why they wouldn't work, you just need to make sure to add an empty item if there is no product in that category.

Comment: @H.B. How will you solve the font sizing problem?

Comment: I want to know what you want the font to do, what was the problem with the Viewbox etc.